# SQLAlchemy: Single Table Inheritance, same column in childs

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, single-table-inheritance

Im currently mapping a class hierarchy using the single table inheritance strategy (it is not possible for me to use joined). This hierarchy might look like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on' : type,
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'parent'
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    type = Column(String(32), nullable = False)

class Child1(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child1' }

    property1 = Column(Integer)

class Child2(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child2' }

    property1 = Column(Integer)

class Child3(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child3' }

    other_property = Column(Integer)
```

Well the problem is that I want to have a `property1` on both `Child1` and `Child2` but not on `Child3`. The current code above results in an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column 'property1' on class <class
'__main__.Child2'>  conflicts with existing column 'mytable.property1'
```

I could of course add another layer to the inheritance hierarchy which `Child1` and `Child2` derive from and contains the `property1` column, but `Child1` and `Child2` are hardly related to each other, though I want to reuse the same database column for both classes.

I already tried to add `property1 = Child1.property1` to `Child2` but that didnt worked (the instance values were not stored in the database for `Child2`)

Can anyone point out how to reuse a column already defined by another child class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adapting directly from the documentation at [Resolving Column Conflicts](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#resolving-column-conflicts):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    type = Column(String(32), nullable = False)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on' : type,
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'parent'
    }

class Child1(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child1' }

    @declared_attr
    def property1(cls):
        return Parent.__table__.c.get('property1', Column(Integer))

class Child2(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child2' }

    @declared_attr
    def property1(cls):
        return Parent.__table__.c.get('property1', Column(Integer))

class Child3(Parent):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity' : 'child3' }

    other_property = Column(Integer)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)
s.add_all([Child1(property1=1), Child2(property1=2), Child3(other_property=3)])
s.commit()

for p in s.query(Parent):
    if isinstance(p, (Child1, Child2)):
        print p.property1
    elif isinstance(p, Child3):
        print p.other_property
```